# Trying to understand this location.href.match JS RegExp parts

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to understand this javascript regular expression.

Can anyone give me an explanation about this regexp parts?

```
location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com/i)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

lets break it up in bits:

`^http:\/\/`= the string has to begin with `http://`. The backslashes are there because if they wouldn't, the slashes would end the regex pattern.

`(www\.)?` = matches `www.` if it exists (that's what the question mark is for)

`example.com` = string must be followed with `example.com`

`i` = case insensitive

So these are possible matches:

- `http://example.com`
- `http://www.example.com`
- `http://www.EXAMPLE.COM`
- `http://www.example.com/some/page/`

Unfortunately, the regex wouldn't match the HTTPS protocol. We can use the same method applied to `www.` using the question mark:

`/^http(s)?:\/\/(www\.)?example.com/i`

Comment: if I write /g after /i, like: location.href.match(/^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com/i/g) it will still give me the same result? or it should be /ig thank you!

Comment: @GordenGram should be only /ig

Comment: @GordenGram What @godka said. However, you should remove the `^` character. If you use the global flag, it should match multiple URL's within one string so it can't always be at the start of the string.

Answer (score 2):

```
^           - start of line
http:       - http:
\/\/        - //
(www\.)?    - www. 0 or 1 time
example.com - example.com
```

The `i` flag means the entire expression is case insensitive so `HTTP://WWW.EXAMPLE.COM` will also match.

Answer (score 1):

```
/^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com/i

1) ^ - carret (matches start of line / string)
2) http: - matches the actual 'http:' string
3) \/\/ - matches // (needs escaping with \)
4) (www\.)? - can contain or not the string 'www.' (? = 0 or 1 times)
5) example.com - matches the actual 'example.com' string
6) trailing i - case insensitive
```

Answer (score 1):

The regexp :

```
/^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com/i
```

As explained in javascript the regexp is in the forme (http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_obj_regexp.asp) :

```
/pattern/modifiers
```

**So the pattern** :

```
^http:\/\/(www\.)?example.com
```

`^` start with

`http:\/\/` 'http://' with the slashes escaped

`(www\.)?` 0 or 1 time 'www.'

`example.com` 'example', any char exept newline, 'com'

if you want 'example.com' only, use `example\.com`

**The modifier :**

`i` case insensitive